Errors when computing bandwidth in GWR with R?
I am working with a large dataset (52.769 rows). I need to compute the bandwidth for GWR using dm. calib from GWmodel package.  When I run the code, I get the following error: Error: std::bad_alloc and nothing else.
How do I fix this?
This is my code:
xy <- st_coordinates(dt)

spdf <- as(dt, "Spatial")

dm.calib <- gw.dist(dp.locat = coordinates(spdf))

I tried to compute manually, but unfortunately, there was still an error. This is my code
coordinates <- data.frame(x = dt$xcoord, y = dt$ycoord)

dm.calib <- as.matrix(dist(coordinates))
dm.calib 

